# Recent files and locations listed in Dolphin and other applications are very old, date is false

Tags: files, kde, plasma5, dolphin

I have noticed that files and locations shown in Dolphin (and thus in KDE file dialog too) under 'Recent files' and 'Recent locations' are not recent at all. All I see is files (in 'Recent Files') and folders (in 'Recent Locations') from my system but that I am 100% sure I have not accessed in months, while the system seems to think that happened a few minutes ago.

But I have also noticed that recent files and recent applications are also askew in the Application Dashboard launcher too: they are too old, 'recent files' there are those from the list in Dolphin, the 'recent applications' have not been used at all in weeks or even months!

It is as if those lists are stuck in time, at a certain date when I've looked at those foobar2000 icons and files:

[image]

**That time information saying number of minutes or some hour "today" is completely false: I had nothing to do with those files in months!**

The same incorrect "recent" files and folders are listed by `recentlyused:/files/` and `recentlyused:/locations/`.

Discussing [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/sunkjr/what_data_is_recent_files_and_recent_locations/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) I see that `recentdocuments:/` as path in Dolphin or the files in `~/.local/share/RecentDocuments` include the real "recent files", related to my activity during last days and hours.

Surely, these are the ones that should be listed in Dolphin panel "Recent" too.

Could this be a bug or is it a problem with my system?

This is in Kubuntu 22.04 (updated from 20.04, where I had the same problem), Plasma 5.24., Dolphin 21.12.2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have foumd a workaround, based on [this](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=137676#p368459).

`timeline:/calendar/` and `timeline:/today/` in Dolphin show both files and folders recently accessed.

Adding them to "Places" in Dolphin adds them automatically under the "Recent" panel (therefore this shouldn't be hidden), which makes me think the `timeline` protocol is the one used by that panel anyway.  (For some reason the default entries must have got corrupted on my system.) The main difference between the default view and the one provided by `timeline:/` is that this does not separate files from folders.

[image]

---

Update: that was fixed in later Plasma versions, it seems.